# PHP Curl Login https for Esse3

Tags: php, ssl, curl, authentication

I'm trying to do a login in a Esse3 Platform with Curl PHP.
Here the snippet:

```
<?
 function get_jsessionid($url){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  print_r($ch);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  $result=curl_exec ($ch);
  preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
  $cookies = array();
  foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
   parse_str($item, $cookie);
   $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
  }
  return $cookies['JSESSIONID'];
 }

  $username='';
  $password='';
  $baseurl='https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/Home.do';
  $loginurl= 'https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do;jsessionid=' . get_jsessionid($baseurl);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$loginurl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
  $result=curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);

  print_r($result);
```

Obviously now I've deleted my credentials, but the code doesn't work. I've tried a lot of time with differents snippet but login doesn't go.
Do you have any solution? 
Ps: code works, but the remote webapp give me a login error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/Home.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match("/Set-cookie: (.*)\n/iU", $response, $matches);
$cookie = trim(substr($matches[1], strpos($matches[1],':')));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://webstudenti.unica.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$username}:{$password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**UPDATE** (extra configuration)

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
```

Comment: I've tried you snippet, but i receive this error: 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 15:48:58 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Pragma: No-cache Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0 Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 11978

Comment: Try to add this conf:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');